# Why does a Fortran POINTER require a TARGET?

Tags: pointers, fortran

Why does the [Fortran 90 Specification](ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N001-N1100/N692.pdf) specify (5.2.8) that the TARGET keyword must be used to associate a POINTER to it? Why isn't every type a valid TARGET?

For example,

`INTEGER, POINTER :: px
INTEGER, TARGET :: x
x = 5
px => x`
 
**is** valid syntax but

`INTEGER, POINTER :: px
INTEGER :: x
x = 5
px => x`
 
is **not valid**.

Why must this be?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An item that might be pointed to could be aliased to another item, and the compiler must allow for this.   Items without the target attribute should not be aliased and the compiler can make assumptions based on this and therefore produce more efficient code.

Comment: My previous comment was not accurate. Pointer/target association can lead to some really tricky situations. I recommend some further reading if you are inexperienced with pointer/target association practices in Fortran. See, for example, this link https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/709550

Answer (score 2):

Pointers in fortran are different than pointers in c. In fortran 90 pointers were provided with few restriction like having a target. This was done to address speed issue and to keep pointer usage safe. Although one call make allocatable pointers which do not need to specify a target. Dig deeper and you will find them!!

Answer (score 0):

For better compiler optimization. When your code runs on 1K-100K cores speed does matter.

Btw TARGET is not always used. For example in situations when the pointer is being used for allocating memory.

```
...
real, pointer :: p(:), x
...
allocate(p(15))
...
x => p(1:5)
...
nullify(x)
deallocate(p)
...
```

Comment: Depending on the compiler, you have to allocate(x(5)) in order for this to work.

Comment: @AlanSe Which compiler please ? The shown set of lines seems right.

Comment: @user49734 TARGET is not necessary here (and even forbidden) because a pointer is always "targettable"