# Does the target attribute affect efficiency of Fortran programs?

Tags: performance, pointers, fortran

I have read [difference between POINTER and ALLOCATABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023371/difference-between-pointer-and-allocatable?lq=1) and [Why does a Fortran POINTER require a TARGET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730065/why-does-a-fortran-pointer-require-a-target/4732214#4732214) and they have really good answers.

It seems that the most efficient choice is to use allocatables for big arrays and pointers for things like linked lists, trees, etc.

Now, if I have my nice efficient allocatable variable, would the target attribute somehow affect the way it is accessed or how the compiler optimizes code with it? Is it advisable to do this?

For instance, I can think of my coordinate triplet:

```
real, dimension(:),allocatable :: x,y,z
```

and within a subroutine I would like to point at them in a cyclic way using a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permute the directions (i.e., (x,y,z) --> (y,z,x)), then a pointer is not necessary as you can use an `if-else` condition with allocatables:

```
    if(dir == 1) then
       allocate(x(1:nx),y(1:ny),z(1:nz))
    elseif(dir == 2) then
       allocate(x(1:ny),y(1:nz),z(1:nx))
    elseif(dir == 3) then
       allocate(x(1:nz),y(1:nx),z(1:ny))
    endif
```

This should enable code re-use since you always have your parallel direction in `x` and your perpendicular directions in `y` and `z`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Still I'd like to know the effect of a target attribute on an allocatable variable.

Comment: Not all compilers require the allocatable variables to have a target attribute.  The target attribute is basically used to tell the compiler that the variable may possibly be aliased.  The compiler can then make a decision on generating more efficient code.  It is very compiler dependent.  The easiest way is to set a breakpoint in the code and see the difference in code generation with and without the target attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to be compiler dependent and I personally have no knowledge of how compiler developers handle this situation in practice. However, this might depend on the size/complexity of derived data type and also the type of {intent(in), intent(out), intent(inout)} used in subroutine. Compare the following types:

```
type ex1
   real :: a ! only one member
end type ex1
```

and

```
type ex2
real, dimension(:), allocatable :: a    ! member 1
type(complicated), allocatable  :: b(:) ! member 2
type(more_complicated) :: c
! :
! :
!                           still has more 200 members!
end type ex2
```

Assuming that you don't want to point to the objects made of "ex2 data type" it in your program, I think removing target attribute might improve the speed of the program because compiler can significantly optimize the interior structure of ex2 with the assumption of no aliasing will be done on that during runtime. The same argument holds regarding intent() when used as an argument to a subroutine.

However for simple "type ex1" I really wouldn't care if I leave it with or without target attribute when I don't intent to point to it in my program.