# Impact performance of the TARGET attribute (not the POINTER attribute)

Tags: fortran

The question of performance impact due to the presence of the TARGET attribute was asked many times, but the answers lack of concrete examples.

The question [Why does a Fortran POINTER require a TARGET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4730065/4866475) has a nice anwser:

> An item that might be pointed to could be aliased to another item, and the compiler must allow for this. Items without the target attribute should not be aliased and the compiler can make assumptions based on this and therefore produce more efficient code.

I realize that the optimizations depend on the compiler and the processor instruction set, but what actually are these optimizations?

Consider the following code:

```
subroutine complexSubroutine(tab)
    double precision, dimension(:) :: tab
    !...
    ! very mysterious complex instructions performed on tab
    !...
end subroutine
```

What are the optimization that the compiler could perform for this code

```
double precision, dimension(very large number) :: A
call complexSubroutine(A)
```

and not for this code?

```
double precision, dimension(very large number), target :: A
call complexSubroutine(A)
```

Comment: That obviously depends on the "very mysterious complex instructions performed on tab". Especially, what you do with the pointers there. (If you don't do anything with pointers the `target` is almost irrelevant).

Comment: It could also affect the aliasing in dummy arguments, but you have just one argument there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the dummy argument `tab` in `complexSubroutine` in the question **does not** have the TARGET attribute.  **Inside the subroutine** the compiler can assume that `tab` is not aliased, and the below discussion is moot.  **The issue applies to the scope calling the subroutine.**

If the compiler knows that there is no possibility of aliasing, then the compiler knows that there is no possibility of the storage for two objects overlapping.  The potential for overlap has direct implications for some operations.  As a simple example, consider:

```
INTEGER, xxx :: forward(3)
INTEGER, xxx :: reverse(3)
forward = [1,2,3]
reverse(1:3:1) = forward(3:1:-1)
```

The Fortran standard defines the semantics of assignment such that `reverse` should end up with the value `[3,2,1]`.

If `xxx` does not include POINTER or TARGET, then the compiler knows that `forward` and `reverse` do not overlap.  It can execute the array assignment in a straight forward manner, perhaps by working backwards through the elements on the right hand side and forwards through the elements on the left hand, as suggested by the subscript triplets, and doing the element by element assignment "directly".

However, if `forward` and `reverse` are TARGETs, then they may well overlap.  The straight forward manner suggested above may fail to produce the result required by the standard.  If the two names are associated with exactly the same underlying sequence of data objects, then the transfer of `reverse(3)` to `forward(1)` will change the value that `reverse(1)` later references.  With the naive approach above that fails to accommodate aliasing, `reverse` would end up with the value `[3,2,3]`.

To deliver the result required by the standard, compilers may create a temporary object to hold the result of evaluating the right hand side of the assignment, effectively:

```
INTEGER, TARGET :: forward(3)
INTEGER, TARGET :: reverse(3)
INTEGER :: temp(3)
temp = forward(3:1:-1)
reverse(1:3:1) = temp
```

The presence and additional operations associated with the temporary may result in a performance impact.

The potential for aliasing to break the otherwise straight forward and simple approach to an operation is a general problem for many situations.  In the absence of compiler and runtime smarts to determine that aliasing isn't a problem in a particular situation, the creation and use of temporaries is a general solution, with the general potential for a performance impact.

The potential for aliasing not immediately apparent to the compiler may also prevent the compiler assuming that the value of an object won't change when it doesn't see any explicit reference to the object that would imply a change.

```
INTEGER, TARGET :: x
...much later...
x = 4
CALL abc
IF (x == 4) THEN
  ...
```

The compiler, not knowing anything about procedure `abc`, cannot, in general, assume that `x` is not modified inside procedure `abc` - perhaps a pointer to `x` is available to the procedure in some way and the procedure has used that pointer to indirectly modify `x`.  If `x` did not have the TARGET attribute, then the compiler knows that `abc` could not legitimately change its value.  This has implications for the compiler's ability to analyse possible code paths at compile time, and to resequence operations/move operations out of loops, etc.

Comment: Hi Ian, sorry for the necro. In your example, how can `forward` and `reverse` overlap if they're both `target`s? I thought `target` meant they must occupy a unique place in memory. Do you mean if one or both is `pointer`?

Comment: TARGET means that the object may be aliased with another object.  TARGET does not mean "occupy a unique place in memory" (that would rule out aliasing!).  Pointers may be pointer associated with targets, but pointers do not have to be involved in order for objects to be aliased.  Imagine that `forward` and `reverse` are the first and second dummy arguments of a subroutine.  `CALL subroutine(arg, arg)` (i.e. same actual argument for the two dummy arguments) would then result in aliasing.